# Time complexity analysis in data structures and algo

Tags: c++, data-structures, time-complexity, big-o

Can we compare O(m+n) with O(n), are both same because we need to focus only on the highest power?

Comment: For all we know, `m` is exponentially larger than `n`, and then of course `O(m+n)` is much worse than `O(n)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O(m+n) is *two-dimensional* (it has to parameters, m and n) and you can't  reduce it to one dimension without more information about the relationship between m and n.

A concrete example: Many graph algorithms (e.g. depth first search, topological sort) have time complexity O(*v* + *e*), where *v* is the number of vertices and *e* is the number of edges. You can consider two separate types of graph:

- In a dense graph with lots of edges, *e* is proportional to *v*². The time complexity of the algorithm on this type of graph is O(*v + v*²), or O(*v*²).
- In a sparse graph with few edges, *e* is proportional to *v*. The time complexity of the algorithm on this type of graph is O(*v + v*), or O(*v*).

Answer (score 4):

The complexity of both O(m+n) and O(n) is linear in relation to input n. In realtion to m, the complexity of O(m+n) is linear while O(n) is constant.

So, unless we analyse only the input n and assume m to be constant, we cannot in general simplify O(m+n) to O(n).

Sometimes we may be able to combine two input dimensions into one: For example, if m is number of input strings and n is the maximum length of input string, then we might reframe the premise by analysing complexity in relation to total length of all input strings.